# Swift game infinite spawning not working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

i've a problem with my swift game. I want to spawn every 2 seconds two sprites and move them like flappy bird pipes. I tried on this way but my game crashes after the delay. Here is DidMoveToView: ( i jump right on the interesting parts)

```
let distanceToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 140)
    let movePipes = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * distanceToMove)))
    let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes,removePipes])


    let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.0))
    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.initPipes()})
    let spawnAndDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn,delay])
    let spawnAndDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnAndDelay)
    runAction(spawnAndDelayForever)
```

And here is the func of the pipes:

```
func initPipes() {
    let pY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.height - 250) + 250)
    let pipePair = SKNode()
    pipePair.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width + 70, y: 0)
    //PIPE 1
    pipe1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    pipe1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(pY))
    pipe1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(70, 700), center: CGPointMake(70/2, 700/2))
    pipe1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    pipe1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    pipePair.addChild(pipe1)

    //PIPE 2
    pipe2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,1)
    pipe2.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: pipe1.position.y - 150)
    pipe2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(70, 700), center: CGPointMake(35, -700/2))
    pipe2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    pipe2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    pipePair.addChild(pipe2)

    pipePair.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    addChild(pipePair)
}
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Maybe try using an NSTimer() to spawn the pipes?

Comment: @TheCodeComposer Using NSTimer could be a bad idea to spawn objects because it is not affected by view's,scene's or node's paused state. So spawning using action sequence or even update: method and its currentTime passed parameter would be preferred way in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is here

```
pipePair.addChild(pipe1)
```

You are not creating a new pipe but instead using an old one you created somewhere else. The first time through you are not going to have a problem, but if you didn't remove the pipe1 from its parent before you try adding it to a new parent it will crash. I would create your pipe1 and pipe2 in that method instead of having a variable outside of it.

```
func initPipes() {
    let pY = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.height - 250) + 250)
    let pipePair = SKNode()
    pipePair.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width + 70, y: 0)
    //PIPE 1
    let pipe1 = //whatever pipe1 is
    pipe1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    pipe1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: Int(pY))
    pipe1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(70, 700), center: CGPointMake(70/2, 700/2))
    pipe1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    pipe1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    pipePair.addChild(pipe1)

    //PIPE 2
    let pipe2 = //whatever pipe1 is
    pipe2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,1)
    pipe2.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: pipe1.position.y - 150)
    pipe2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(70, 700), center: CGPointMake(35, -700/2))
    pipe2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    pipe2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    pipePair.addChild(pipe2)

    pipePair.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    addChild(pipePair)
}
```

or if the intention is to only have one set of pipes at a time call

```
pipe1.removeFromParent()
pipe2.removeFromParent()
```

before

```
pipePair.addChild(pipe1)
pipePair.addChild(pipe2)
```

Hopefully that makes sense and is helpful.

Comment: It works! thanks a lot! Never thought the problem were the pipe constants declared outside.